# Oxidshop - Get oxSession variable inside tpl file

Tags: oxid

I am trying to print an oxsession variable inside a tpl file. The tpl file is actually a block which extends basketcontents.tpl file. Any idea how I can achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `[{$smarty.session.YOUR_VARIABLE}]`